# How to count the number of sequential repeats in a column of data in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

If I have a very long text file like this:

```
A
A
B
B
A
A
A
B
A
A
B
A
...
```

I'd like to find the number of 'A's in a row (e.g. 1, 2, 3...), and then report how many of each sequence I have.

So the above snippet would give me 3:1, 2:2: 1:1, where the first number is the number of sequential 'A's, and the second number is how many of these sequences occur in the whole file.

Is this possible in bash/awk/sed etc?

I have tried using awk to count the number of intances:

```
awk ' BEGIN {count=0;}  { if ($1 == "A") count+=1} end {print $count}'
```

but I am not sure how to get information on the sequence length.

Comment: it NOT about *how many instances of 'A's I have in a **row*** - it's about how many sequences of `A`s (row-wise) you have through the file

Comment: not able to understand how output is derived, could you try to add more details.. for ex: there are 2 As at start of input but output starts with 3... also, please add what you've tried to solve this... see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a single command :

```
awk '/A/{c++;next}
     c{a[c]++;c=0}
     END{if(c){a[c]++}
         for(i in a) {print i":"a[i]}
     }' <file>
```

- `/A/{c++;next}` If the line contains `A` increase the counter `c` and move the the next line
- `c{a[c]++; c=0}` If `c` is different from `ZERO`, increase the frequency of `c` stored in `a[c]` and set `c` to `ZERO`
- at the `END` print the frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

```
< your_file \
  uniq -c | # count the number of occurrences in a row
  awk '$2 == "A" { print $1 }' | # keep only the counts of “A” (and not the “A” themselves)
  sort | # sort the counts
  uniq -c | # count the number of occurrences of each count
  awk '{ print $2 " " $1 }' | # swap the count of count and the count
  sort -nrk1 | # sort by count, numerically, decreasing
  tr ' ' : # use a colon as separator instead of a space
```

The output:

```
3:1
2:2
1:1
```

Comment: Probably works, though condensing it all into a single Awk script would probably improve both performance and legibility.

Comment: Yes, this works very well thanks. I have another file with '1's and '0's instead of 'A's and 'B's which trips this up, but if I replace 'grep 'A'' with 'awk '$1 == "1"'' it works perfectly.

Comment: @birac: you probably meant `$2`, not `$1`, as the first column is the count, not the original line

Comment: I've removed the grep altogether; the first use of awk can do the filtering much better.

Comment: backslashes are redundant after pipe symbol.

Comment: @karakfa: spent years writing shell script and had never realized that… Thank you! I'm removing them — and so the related note which is pointless, now.

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ if ($1 == "A") { k++ } else if (k) { a[k]++; k=0 } }
     END{ if (k) a[k]++; for (i in a) print i ":" a[i] }' file
```

The output:

```
1:1
2:2
3:1
```

Comment: Consider adding additional check inside `END` as this won't count `A` sequences at the end of the file.

Comment: @PesaThe, ok, let's do it

Answer (score 1):

a non-`awk` pipeline

```
$ uniq -c file | grep A | sort -r | 
  rev | uniq -c | rev | sed 's/ A /:/;s/  *//g' | paste -sd,
```

gives

```
3:1,2:2,1:1
```

Comment: Is it possible to get each output on separate line?